# Refresh cache when release new version on pwa

Tags: web, caching, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

Has someone know how to update cache when release new version on PWA

I know can use localstorage to compare version string with api ,when restart the app will reload page and forceUpdate it

but what if user didn’t close the app just minimize it, and come back without restart?